# Getting accelerometer value in a button press

Tags: android, android-sensors

I am trying for a sample project for storing android accelerometer value on a button click, It is working and i get the value, Now i want to store accelerometer reading starts from button click and end on button release, I have tried using **OnTouchListener** But i am not able to control the accelerometer, Any one tried this before, Any kind of answer will be help full for me

```
layout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            sensorMgr = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
            mAccelerometer = sensorMgr.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
            sensorMgr.registerListener((SensorEventListener) getApplicationContext(), mAccelerometer,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            sensorMgr.unregisterListener(this);
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

This is the code i am using to control the accelerometer,But my app goes to force close giving  error in logcat is

```
03-27 12:36:29.570: I/TextToSpeech.java(28968): initTts() successfully bound to service
03-27 12:36:29.578: D/SensorManager(28968): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 1
03-27 12:36:29.578: D/SensorManager(28968): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 2
03-27 12:36:29.578: D/SensorManager(28968): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 3
03-27 12:36:29.578: D/SensorManager(28968): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 4
03-27 12:36:29.578: D/SensorManager(28968): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 5
03-27 12:36:29.578: D/SensorManager(28968): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 6
03-27 12:36:29.578: D/SensorManager(28968): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 7
03-27 12:36:29.578: D/SensorManager(28968): ====>>>>>Num Sensor: 0
03-27 12:36:30.570: W/dalvikvm(28968): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
03-27 12:36:30.578: E/AndroidRuntime(28968): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-27 12:36:30.578: E/AndroidRuntime(28968): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application
03-27 12:36:30.578: E/AndroidRuntime(28968):    at com.example.androidphonemotion.MainActivity$1.onTouch(MainActivity.java:59)
03-27 12:36:30.578: E/AndroidRuntime(28968):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3934)
03-27 12:36:30.578: E/AndroidRuntime(28968):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:903)
03-27 12:36:30.578: E/AndroidRuntime(28968):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
03-27 12:36:30.578: E/AndroidRuntime(28968):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
03-27 12:36:30.578: E/AndroidRuntime(28968):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
03-27 12:36:30.578: E/AndroidRuntime(28968):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:869)
03-27 12:36:30.578: E/AndroidRuntime(28968):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1733)
03-27 12:36:30.578: E/AndroidRuntime(28968):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1151)
03-27 12:36:30.578: E/AndroidRuntime(28968):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2096)
03-27 12:36:30.578: E/AndroidRuntime(28968):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1717)
03-27 12:36:30.578: E/AndroidRuntime(28968):    at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2215)
03-27 12:36:30.578: E/AndroidRuntime(28968):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1886)
03-27 12:36:30.578: E/AndroidRuntime(28968):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-27 12:36:30.578: E/AndroidRuntime(28968):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-27 12:36:30.578: E/AndroidRuntime(28968):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3689)
03-27 12:36:30.578: E/AndroidRuntime(28968):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-27 12:36:30.578: E/AndroidRuntime(28968):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-27 12:36:30.578: E/AndroidRuntime(28968):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
03-27 12:36:30.578: E/AndroidRuntime(28968):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
03-27 12:36:30.578: E/AndroidRuntime(28968):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You want to read just one value?

Comment: I am trying to read the whole value,but if i get the one value which is the final motion value it will be more help full

Comment: You have not register listener, that is why you get force close when unregister

Comment: sorry i forget that line,the error is same...

Comment: Just log and see how many time onTouch is called while the button is still being touch.

Comment: Now i get the error log and i am posting it

Comment: I can't tell you why you're getting forced close. I've edited my answer. Maybe you try it that way? My own app is working like this.

Comment: It seems the touch event is being send many time. To make sure just do Log.d("onTouch", "onTouch Eventdown") and put it on the ACTION_DOWN and see how many times it is called before the app is forced close.

Answer (score 2):

I'd register and unregister the sensors Listener on Button click, storing the values can be performed by setting onSensorChangedListener for the sensor.

```
mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    //perform storing values of event
}
```

Alternatively you could register in `onResume()` and unregister in `onPause()`. To start/stop storing of values you could then set a flag in onTouch (if you want to record while holding the button) or onClick (to start with the first button touch and stop with the second). You would then have to put another if-clause in your `onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)` so it will only store information if flag is true. That way you don't have problems with registering the listener, but the battery drain could be higher since the sensor is alway active as long as the app is running.

Comment: i am using the same thing in my code but how i can control using a button,any way let me try and i ill get you back..

Comment: It is not working and i have updated my question  please check.

Comment: exactly what i am trying now is this,thank you very much and +1 for helping me

Comment: @user2020354: please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your issue. I'm downvoting the question until you do: please ping me when you have.

Comment: it is use full but i am sorry it is not the exact answer what i am trying, i  am sorry